# Linq query to count field in datatable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, linq

I have a datatable that contains a column as "Column-A". Now if that column contains a value of "Y" or "N", i need to set the count variable.

for that i need to check that if count is greater that 0 or not. How the same can be achieved with the help of LINQ?

Please guide!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, it will count the number of rows that contain "Y" or "N" within `Column-A`:

```
int count = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
               .Count(row => row.Field<string>("Column-A") == "Y"
                          || row.Field<string>("Column-A") == "N");
```

I think this is what you're trying to do? If I misunderstood your question, please let me know.

Comment: word 'row' doesn't show up in intellisense. I'm using .net 3.5/Vs 2008

Comment: @Xor power Add a reference to `System.Linq`.

Comment: @Xor power It should work then, did you try the whole example?

Comment: @Xor power `row` is just the name of the `DataRow` parameter we're passing to the predicate function required by the `Enumerable.Count` method, it's not a language keyword. You could use any identifier there and it should still work.

Comment: let me try and will update the question/comment later if anything is not what i needed. Wait for some time (at least half a day!).. thanks for inputs... :-)